# Grouping an array on the basis of its first element, without duplication in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, grouping

I'm executing an active record command *Product.pluck(:category_id, :price)*, which returns an array of 2 element arrays:

```
[
  [1, 500],
  [1, 100],
  [2, 300]
]
```

I want to group on the basis of the first element, creating a hash that looks like:

```
{1 => [500, 100], 2 => [300]}
```

group_by seems logical, but replicates the entire array.  I.e. *a.group_by(&:first)* produces:

```
{1=>[[1, 500], [1, 100]], 2=>[[2, 300]]}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do a secondary transform to it:

```
Hash[
  array.group_by(&:first).collect do |key, values|
    [ key, values.collect { |v| v[1] } ]
  end
]
```

Alternatively just map out the logic directly:

```
array.each_with_object({ }) do |item, result|
  (result[item[0]] ||= [ ]) << item[1]
end
```

Comment: Wow. I love this construct

Answer (score 5):

This one-liner seemed to work for me.

```
array.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.each(&:shift)] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're grouping by the first element, just remove it with `shift` and turn the result into a hash:

```
array.group_by(&:first).map do |key, value|
  value = value.flat_map { |x| x.shift; x }
  [key, value]
end #=> {1=>[500, 100], 2=>[300]}
```

Comment: This made sense as well, I went with each_with_object since it avoided hashification

Answer (score 2):

I do not like the destructive operation.

`array.group_by(&:first).map { |id, a| [id, a.map(&:last)] }.to_h`

Answer (score 0):

Used this functionality several times in my app, added extension to an array:

```rb
# config/initializers/array_ext.rb
class Array
  # given an array of two-element arrays groups second element by first element, eg:
  # [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]].group_second_by_first #=> {1 => [2, 3], 2 => [4]}
  def group_second_by_first
    each_with_object({}) { |(first, second), h| (h[first] ||= []) << second }
  end
end
```